# Why is a Component method using fetch and settingState in response not causing a componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, setstate

I want to generate a menu dynamically depending on user connected state and user role. I have a json file from which feeds the React app with all menu choices. The problem is that it does offer the "login" and "contact" options, which don't require any specific role or for a user to be logged in, but when I log in with the App's login() method, in which I use the fetch API and set the new state in the response, it doesn't refresh the menu choices (which is done in componentDidMount() method. It keeps serving me the login and contact options. I want to switch the login for logout when a user is connected.

I tried a bunch of stuff, but putting logs and debuggers in my code, I noticed the component doesn't re-render after the setState that's called in the login() fetch operation, but the state is indeed getting changed. I'm curious as to why the setState is not firing componentDidMount()?

menu.json

```
[
    {
        "txt": "login",
        "idRole": null
    },
    {
        "txt": "logout",
        "idRole": null
    },
    {
        "txt": "register",
        "idRole": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "txt": "profile",
        "idRole": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "txt": "contact",
        "idRole": null
    }
]
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from 'container/Header.js'
import Footer from './container/Footer'
import Login from './container/Login'
import menu from '../json-form-file/menu.json'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isMenuOpen: false,
            isLoggedIn: false,
            menu: null,
            page: null,
            user: null
        }
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this)
        this.selectPage = this.selectPage.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    }
    toggleMenu () {
        this.setState({ isMenuOpen: !this.state.isMenuOpen })
    }
    selectPage (event) {
        this.setState({ isMenuOpen: !this.state.isMenuOpen, page: event.target.textContent })
        const toggler = document.getElementsByClassName('toggler')[0]
        toggler.checked = !toggler.checked
    }
    login (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const requestBody = createLoginRequestBody(Array.from(event.target.parentElement.children))
        clearLoginFields(Array.from(event.target.parentElement.children))
        if (requestBody.username !== undefined && requestBody.pwd !== undefined) {
            fetch('www.someLoginUrl.login', {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => this.setState({ user: response, isLoggedIn: true, page: null }))
        }
    }
    logout (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const toggler = document.getElementsByClassName('toggler')[0]
        toggler.checked = !toggler.checked
        this.setState({ user: null, isLoggedIn: false, page: null, isMenuOpen: !this.state.isMenuOpen })
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log('im mounting')
        const newMenu = this.refreshMenuSelection(menu)
        this.setState({ menu: newMenu })
    }
    refreshMenuSelection (list) {
        const newMenu = []
        list.map((item) => {
            if (item.txt === 'login' && this.state.isLoggedIn === false) newMenu.push(item)
            if (item.txt === 'logout' && this.state.isLoggedIn === true) newMenu.push(item)
            if (item.idRole === null && item.txt !== 'login' && item.txt !== 'logout') newMenu.push(item)
            if (this.state.user !== null && item.idRole.includes(this.state.user.id_role)) newMenu.push(item)
        })
        return newMenu
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header
                    menu={this.state.menu}
                    toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}
                    selectPage={this.selectPage}
                    logout={this.logout}
                    color={this.state.isMenuOpen ? secondaryColor : primaryColor} />
                {this.state.page === 'login' ? <Login login={this.login} /> : null}
                <Footer color={this.state.isMenuOpen ? secondaryColor : primaryColor} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const createLoginRequestBody = (inputs) => {
    const requestObject = {}
    inputs.map((input) => {
        if (input.id === 'username') Object.assign(requestObject, { username: input.value })
        if (input.id === 'pwd') Object.assign(requestObject, { pwd: input.value })
    })
    return requestObject
}
```

When a user is not logged in, he could see only login and contact. When logged in, he could see logout instead of login, contact and all other choices relevant to his role.

Comment: Not the most beautiful code, but I'm just trying some things before cleaning up.

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only be called first time component mounts. So if you want to update then use other lifecycle method like componentDidUpdate or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing causes a `componentDidMount` to run again, it's a lifecycle hook which runs only one time through the component's lifecycle. Everything that goes inside `componentDidMount` will only run once (after the first render), so if you need to react to a change to perform imperative code, take a look at `componentDidUpdate`. You should also take a look in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 0):

As said, `componentDidMount` only runs once when the component is first mounted. If you use `setState()` after the first mount, the function will not respond to it. If you want to do that, maybe you ought to use `componentDidUpdate` which does react to this type of change. And also, there's another thing wrong with your code. If you use `setState()` and use `componentDidUpdate` then it will change the state again and calling the function again until the program crashes. So if you don't want to cause that, maybe also remove that or move it to a new `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: But login is only called when you attempt to login. What you describe is some kind of recursivity. Why will it be recursive? componentDidUpdate() method doesn't fire the login() method.

Comment: Excuse me? Try to change it first and see what happends.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who guided me to the componentDidUpdate() method. This modified bit of code helped me achieve what I wanted. In the future I'll clean up the code to remove the justLoggedIn, as that might not be necessary, but without that it was giving my the setState depth error.

```js
    login (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const requestBody = createLoginRequestBody(Array.from(event.target.parentElement.children))
        clearLoginFields(Array.from(event.target.parentElement.children))
        if (requestBody.username !== undefined && requestBody.pwd !== undefined) {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/login', {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => this.setState({ user: response, justLoggedIn: true, isLoggedIn: true }))
        }
    }
    logout (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const toggler = document.getElementsByClassName('toggler')[0]
        toggler.checked = !toggler.checked
        this.setState({ user: null, justLoggedOut: true, isLoggedIn: false, isMenuOpen: !this.state.isMenuOpen })
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        if (this.state.user === null) this.setState({ menu: this.refreshMenuSelection(menu) })
    }
    componentDidUpdate () {
        if (this.state.user !== null && this.state.justLoggedIn) this.setState({ menu: this.refreshMenuSelection(menu), justLoggedIn: false, page: null })
        if (this.state.user === null && this.state.justLoggedOut) this.setState({ menu: this.refreshMenuSelection(menu), justLoggedOut: false, page: null })
    }
```

Comment: Wait. You can accept whatever answer you found best.